# pantheon-mail horizontal elongation

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-mail

Mail application gets elongated.
And no email is readable due to less vertical space.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to drag the window back to a more normal size? Does the window "remember" the correct size when you close and re-launch it?

Comment: No, When i try to do so, it will again start elongating. 

For the second question, the problem remains even after restarting of application.

Comment: It just started for me too. It opens, keeps expanding, and nothing can stop it.

Comment: Callista Graves, Yeah thats the same I'm experiencing here. 

So, I uninstalled pantheon-mail and installed geary.

Comment: Same exact issue. Started a thread before I saw your post; this occurred to me after a bit of a delay on Geary/Freya and now with Loki Mail after a week or so of blissful use (I really like the client overall). Noticed that the stretch was much more extreme on Freya... Not sure that's terribly informative. [![Mail extended gui](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F11NN.png)](http://i.stack.imgur.com/F11NN.png) What sort of box are you running? My Loki install is a new zippy development system, my last machine somewhat less so, but both are Lenovos. Possibly a GTK issue with Lenovo drivers? I don't want t

Comment: Follow the bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1631672

Answer (score 6):

To fix this issue you need to **kill/close** pantheon-mail and then run the command

> **dconf reset -f /org/pantheon/mail/**

I believe this is only a temporary solution. If you have Elementary Tweaks installed you can add that command to **Cerbere** so is constantly running in the back.

Comment: This did not work for me. I have to navigate to the dconf-editor and reset all the values to default. It worked after that.

Answer (score 3):

This is a **bug**. Please [subscribe to its ticket](https://bugs.launchpad.net/pantheon-mail/+bug/1547949) in the bug tracker to receive notifications when the devs need help testing a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I replaced the window and resized it first vertically, which really goes slow. (only some pixels a second) When the window had the correct width again, I could resize it easily to the normal height.

Comment: Thanks Brent. I'll give it a shot. Did your fix persist on reboot? [UPDATE]
Strange... while I was able to resize vertically, horizontal is locked (at the wide width).

Comment: Try right click in the title bar and use the resize option. I never had this problem again, just once.