# Mail is getting automatically bigger and bigger

Tags: pantheon-mail

Today the mail app has a strange behavior. The window was getting bigger and bigger in width. I'm sending a print screen. I have already reboot my computer and also reinstalled the mail and still happening.

Every time that I open it, it gets wider.

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: I found a tip to workaround [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/8024/pantheon-mail-horizontal-elongation).